# Github action discord message multi row

Tags: github, discord, bots, github-actions, action

I would like to make it possible to send a message on a specific discord channel via a github action.

I succeeded, but I'm having the problem that I can't wrap the text.

See pictures.

[image]

The result I get:

[image]

The result I would like to get:

[image]

Code:

```yaml
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
        message:
name: Bot
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - uses: Ilshidur/action-discord@master
          with:
           args: "${{ github.event.inputs.message }}"
          env:
            DISCORD_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.DISCORD_WEBHOOK }}
```

Comment: Have you verified if a hardcoded message including `\n` works with `args` with https://github.com/Ilshidur/action-discord?

Comment: @Azeem: I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Neither did I. Looks like you have to employ some other method to implement this. Maybe, get `\n` from the `message`, transform this to what Discord can render as newline in a separate step and pass that to `action-discord`.

Comment: Please take a look at this listing of Discord Markdown (https://www.writebots.com/discord-text-formatting/) or find some official resources too. Maybe, you may simply transfer `\n` to `<br>` and that would render as newline in Dsicord. It could be a possiblity but you need to test this on your side.